# How to set an image on another view on dismissing current view in iphone?

Tags: objective-c

How to set an image on another view on dismissing current view in iphone??

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want this to happen when a view disappears. When a view is unloaded various methods get called. I think one of them is called viewDidUnload, check the docs for UIView and see what methods it has.